# Monitor Data sent from Android app to Php server in Real time

Tags: java, php, android, json

I made an app that sends coordinates over to my php server. I am able to verify that this works because it returns the coordinates to my phone in a specific format that I set.

However, is there a way to monitor the coords in real time as the phone sends them over to the php server. For instance, can I open app/app.php in firefox and have the php code print the coordinates to my screen as I send them one by one?

I am using JSON to pass the data back and forth.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For realtime use a network sniffer. For PHP just output the request values, then you know as well.

Comment: @hakre: Why don't you put that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Because I think that the OP will add more details which will make the question answerable.

Comment: Ok, sounds great. Is there a way to write the input from the phone to say another webpage like a log? How would I go about doing this? All I want is to show that coordinates are received by the webpage for a presentation.

Im new to php and network programming in general. I just started developing an app that requires a server and Ive been snooping around stack overflow. Its been really helpful. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer seems slightly different than what you asked, but I think it could apply

I think a popular solution to this is to use [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

What you will do is use Fiddler to intercept traffic for sniffing or tampering, and set up your phone or app to use the PC running Fiddler as a proxy.

Configure fiddler to accept connections from remote devices, configure a proxy on your android phone or emulator to use the fiddler proxy, then it can sniff and modify all traffic send from the phone.

- [Fiddler help & tutorials](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/)
- [Tutorial: Getting Android Emulator Working With Fiddler](http://aurir.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/tutorial-getting-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler-http-proxy-tool/)

`If you just want to be able to open a webpage on your server that displays coordinates in real time, some sort of ajax poller might be your best bet.`

Create a webpage that uses Ajax to ask the server if any new coordinates have been sent since a given timestamp, have the server respond with the coordinates if any had been sent, append the results to a div in the browser.  Keep polling for new coordinates as long as the browser page is open.